# How to format datetime field from MySQL in a select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

I have a column set to datetime and with a defined format of 0000-00-00 00:00:00, and now I am trying to query with a SELECT statement to format that date after coming out.

I tried `DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%m-%d-%Y')`, but that didn't work.  I want to just pull out the month-day-year...

Is this possible, or do I have to do it after the data has been pulled out and is a PHP function?

Comment: The DATE_FORMAT you provided is correct; I don't see why it doesn't "work" for you.  Could you provide more detail about why it doesn't work?

Comment: After trying to echo it out, it displays nothing..strange..

Comment: is the query definitely executing ok? code extracts that show what the query and what you do with the result would help us find out what's wrong

Comment: Yes the query is fine, I can echo out other elements within an array..

Comment: I dont know if this has something to do with it but the select is using the format of table.fieldname so its DATE_FORMAT(table.fieldname,'%m-%d-%Y')...

Comment: Maybe you should show the whole query?

Comment: is the time actually stored in the database?

Comment: Did you provide an alias for the DATE_FORMAT() expression? And did you use that alias when you fetched the value from PHP?

Comment: SQL: select date_format(...) as mystamp from... and PHP: $result['mystamp']

Comment: Ok, as it turns out it didn't work unless I used an alias...Not sure why that is though...

Comment: @Rick Could you please make an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to alias the DATE_FORMAT function so that the return field would be something that PHP can recognize.

Without an alias the outputted field would be:

$DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%m-%d-%Y')

With an alias:

$date_field

Comment: an alias is just reference to the column, the example u given is incorrect

Comment: @ajreal - PHP reads the column name and uses it as the outputted variable.  When you don't alias a function in your query the column name is unlikely to be readable by php.

Comment: u must be joking .... is return as `COLUMN as WHAT IS IT`, for this case, it return as a column with name `DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%m-%d-%Y')`